# open source mp4 muxer in java

Tags: open-source, containers, mp4, muxer

Is there any Open Source MP4 muxer/writer java project(source written in java, no native code) available?

I have H.264 & AAC raw/elementary streams stored seperate files. I want to mux them and get the .mp4 video file containing both Audio & Video.

Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Mux as in "multiplex", or was it "mix"?

Comment: 'Mux' meaning, generating .mp4 container file by multiplexing h.264 video elementary stream & aac audio elementary stream recorded seperately.

Comment: y do u need it in java ? for android ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [isoparser](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/) library it is as far as I know the only pure Java tool that can mux AAC and H264. It also provides [an example](https://mp4parser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/muxformats/H264Example.java) for precisely the use case you are describing.

Full disclosure: I am the creator of the library.

```
 AACTrackImpl audio= new AACTrackImpl(new FileInputStream("sample.aac").getChannel());
 H264TrackImpl video = new H264TrackImpl(new FileInputStream("sample.h264"));
 Movie m = new Movie();
 m.addTrack(video);
 m.addTrack(audio);

 IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(m);
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.mp4"));
 out.getBox(fos.getChannel());
 fos.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried using it for android but faced an issue, which I have posted on google discussion groups (https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/mp4parser-discussion/a9RbWVs5Kgs).

Comment: Sebastian Annies, your project will be highly useful for Android4.1+ as no mp4 filewriter APIs are present for raw media encoders supported by Jellibean onwards. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493627/mp4-filewriter-in-android-4-1) ...

Answer (score 1):

Previous sample from [isoparser](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/) cannot be compiled with latest sources. 
I`m using folliwing code to mux row h264(from android MediaCodec) into .mp4 container

```
    H264TrackImpl video;
    try {
        video = new H264TrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl("/home/aod/tmp/rec_1392309584754.h264"), "eng", 9, 1);
        Movie m = new Movie();
        m.addTrack(video);

        BasicContainer out = (BasicContainer) new DefaultMp4Builder().build(m);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/aod/tmp/output.mp4"));
        out.writeContainer(fos.getChannel());
        fos.flush();                        
        fos.close();
    } catch ( IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I used the same method, but the problem is that h264 plays too fast. And after muxing it into mp4, it still plays too fast. Have you encountered this problem?

Comment: I did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738890/what-governs-playback-speed-when-encoding-with-androids-mediacodec-mp4parser