# MP4 filewriter in android 4.1+

Tags: android, mp4, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-mediarecorder, muxer

Starting from Android 4.1 (API level 16) MediaCodec APIs have been introduced. These APIs support Elementary stream Decoding & Encoding. Also MediaExtractor API will give elementary track details by analyzing Media streams.

My Question is, I setup a video encoder using MediaCodec API, which gives me encoded file in .h264 format. I want to write .h264 file into a .mp4 file for playing/storing/sharing purposes. I don't find any .MP4 file-writer API for android.  Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks,
Satish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Android 4.3 (API 18) you can use the [MediaMuxer class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) to convert the raw H.264 stream to a .mp4 file (and even merge an audio stream in).

See the EncodeAndMuxTest and CameraToMpegTest sources [on this page](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) for sample code.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14549890) response may be of use.  It suggests using the [isoparser](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/) library.  It works pretty well if you have elementary streams saved to disk, but it doesn't work if you want to live stream from the MediaCodec output.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use FFmpeg (http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/) for muxing h264-file to mp4 container.